# What is the most important feature of SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Now that Microsoft has started giving us a glimpse of what's going to be in [SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/2010/Sneak_Peek/Pages/default.aspx), I would like to know what you think is going to be the most important feature of SharePoint 2010.

Please include some information about your relationship with SharePoint (End-User, Super-User, Administrator, Developer, ...)

Comment: Except those short videos everything else is under NDA :(. So it is to early to discuss the most important feature.

Comment: Well, the videos and SDK doc tells us about a lot of new features like: * Silverlight UI * Visio Services * FAST search engine * Business Connectivity Services * WF40 Workflows * Multi language support * Site collection specific features, Custom actions, upload page ... * Better support for huge lists * LINQ for SP * Client-side LINQ * List added event handler * Upgradable features * Visual Studio integration * ... So I still think it's interesting to get a feel for what makes you most excited

Comment: This question also isn't programming related. But I'm sure you could rephrase it so it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **developer** i like the client side API and LINQ, but i guess the **end users** will find more use of what i could do with the new business data services.

Answer (score 4):

More refined VS integration!

Comment: (+1) I agree Dan, as a .NET developer it shouldn´t matter that I develop using SharePoint. Today the integration is limited (or should I say hard). It looks better in SP 2010

Comment: Funny, this is the one I'm least excited about. Yes it'll make our life as developers a litte easier, but it'll not make it possible for us to do anything which wasn't possible without it. If I should choose if MS should concentrate on the Platform itself or better development tools, then I'd vote for the Platform anytime. The community can make tools (like WSPbuilder) which make development easier, but we can't upgrade the platform

Comment: @Per Jakobsen: you must be a SharePoint Developer. For Developers who are not yet SharePoint Developers - they have not yet resigned themselves to the restrictions like one **server** per developer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Better tools will make it easier for new developers to enter SharePoint development. I though haven't yet seen anything for 2010 which removes the need for developing on a server. (By the way you're not limited to one server per developer, in a lot of cases multiple servers per developer is better)

Answer (score 2):

The developer Dashboard looks VERY promising.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer: Standards compliant HTML output!

Answer (score 0):

So far I'll say that the updated BDC is the most important feature but since integration with 3rd party applications is my daytime job I might be biased

Answer (score 0):

Have not seen how deployment is handled in 2010. But anything that would improve the deployment experience would be very welcome.